# How to store curl responds in a variable in c

Tags: c, http, curl

I am trying to generate curl get request using c program .Here I need to store the response in a variable and I tried with the following code.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <curl/curl.h>
function_pt(void *ptr, size_t size, size_t nmemb, void *stream){
char **response_ptr =  (char**)stream;
*response_ptr = strndup(ptr, (size_t)(size *nmemb));
}
int main(void)
{
  CURL *curl;
  CURLcode res;
  char *response =calloc(1,sizeof(char));
  curl = curl_easy_init();
    if(curl) {
          curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, "http://example.com");
          curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1L);
          curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION, function_pt);
          curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_WRITEDATA, &response);
          res=curl_easy_perform(curl);
          curl_easy_cleanup(curl);
          printf("%s\n",response);
            }

   return 0;
}
```

The data I get form http get request is real time,so i need to continue with the get request and store value in a variable in an iterative manner,only so that I can use the data in all other parts of the program.But the following code works only once and then exit.
How can I do it? Are there any other methods to generate http get request?

Comment: I don't really understand, are you going to send the request multiple times?

Comment: Yes, I am sending request multiple times

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to `calloc()` the pointer if you are going to `strndup()` the original string, assuming that the response is a string is not good because that is not necessarily true.

I would suggest a structure where you can also store the length of the response, so if it's not text but for example a `jpeg` file nothing bad will happen, and you should not call `printf()` unless you check from the response headers that the response is indeed text, and it will be `nul` terminated afaik.